# Port access in iPhone

Tags: iphone, networking, bonjour

I am trying a server to get data "www.example.com" with the port "xxxx" and my ip is "192.168.10.6". The server has to send the response to my app through port "yyyy". I sent a request to the server, but the sever sends the response to the ip "203.146.0.9" port "yyyy". And the server shows the log as "Connection rejected by 203.146.0.9:yyyy(port)".

I am very much beginner to the network programming. According to my knowledge the server sends the response to my DNS/router. Which not accepts the communication on that port.

My iPhone app listens the port of the device and not the dns port. How to make my app to listen the DNS port or else how to make the DNS to forward the response comes from the particular server to my local iP.
I gone through some post and some specified the "Bonjour". But I have no idea about that. Can anyone please help me by pointing out such example or documentation to clear this issue?

Comment: Why does the server have to specify a port to send back to?

Comment: its a PACS server. which connects peer to peer model for security purpose. It communication send and receive all happens through port.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't
Long answer:

Whenever you connect to a server through your iPhone, the phone forwards the request to the carrier's router via 3G or GPRS or some other protocol, which forwards the connection to the destination server. On the receiving end, the server sees the router's IP address, not the phone's. Actually, the phone's IP address only exists on the carrier's router, and nowhere else on the internet. You cannot create a public server from an iPhone (only maybe on a local WiFi connection, or if the carrier assigns the phone a public routable IP address). Therefore, you cannot initiate a connection from your server to some iPhone. If you want two way communication, you can however use the iPhone to connect to the server and on the server side, use that channel to send data to the iPhone. NAT may be another solution, but once again, it requires special provisions from your carrier, which may be an option for you, but usually not your clients having iPhones.

Comment: thanks for the reply. For now I am sticking for the wifi connection. I have seen some apps which gets the data through port on wifi connection.